# Python regex: string does not contain "jpg" and must have "-" and lowercase

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I'm having troubles figuring out a python regex for django urls. I have a certain criteria, but can't seem to come up with the magic formula. In the end its so I can identify which page is a CMS page and pass to the django function the alias url it should load.

Here are some examples of valid strings which would match:

- about-us
- contact-us
- terms-and-conditions
- info/learn-more-pg2
- info/my-example-url

Criteria:

- Must be all lowercase
- Must contain a dash "-"
- Can contain numbers, letters and a slash "/"
- Must be at least 4 characters long and a max of 30 characters
- Cannot contain special characters
- Cannot contain the words:

  - .jpg
  - .gif
  - .png
  - .css
  - .js

Examples which should not match:

- About-Us (has upper case)
- contactus (doesn't have a dash)
- pg (less than 4 characters)
- img/bg.gif (contains ".gif")
- files/my-styles.css (contains ".css")
- my-page@ (has a character other than letters, numbers, dash or slash)

I know this isn't even close yet, but this is as far as I've gotten:

```
(?P<alias>([a-z/-]{4,30}))
```

I apologize for having large requirements, but I just can't get my head wrapped around this regex stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, some of the things you ask for, such as counting the number of characters are inherently hard to do in a regex.
Also, my understanding is that urls are case insensitive.  (At least, anytime I go to a site and I use caps, I arrive and they are all lowercase numbers.)
Also, it would be easier to test _for_ the presence of ".gif" and the like than to negate it.  Could you put a rule for them first, to filter out the urls with them in it before it gets to this rule?

Comment: I have another URL structure that is only going to contain uppercase characters with no slashes or dashes, and all the CMS pages will be lowercase with dashes. Also, the length isn't a priority, if it can't be done or its a performance hog I'd be ok with ditching that.

Comment: @Tyr: How is counting characters hard to do in a regex? Also URLs are *not* case-insensitive, at least not the part after the domain, if you're on Apache (I think).

Comment: Well, I admit I know little about how Apache handles urls, you you could be right.
What I meant to say is regexes can't count more than one thing.  (What regex matches all strings with an equal number of "a"s and "b"s, in any order?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm puzzled as to why several of the commentators find that this is hard to do in a regex. This is exactly what regular expressions are good at.

```
if re.match(
    r"""^             # match start of the string
    (?=.*-)           # assert that there is a dash
    (?!.*\.(?:jpg|gif|png|css|js))  # assert that these words can't be matched
    [a-z0-9/-]{4,30}  # match 4-30 of the allowed characters
    $                 # match the end of the string""", 
    subject, re.VERBOSE):
    # Successful match at the start of the string
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

It is true however that since the `.` isn't among the allowed characters, the check for the forbidden file extensions is not really necessary.

Comment: +1 Damn, regex did it again :) I keep forgetting about lookahead. (But you can drop the `^` when you're going to use `.match` and the outmost parens might be unbalanced because the closing one is in a comment; and why are you using non-grouping on the whole regex?).

Comment: Or, it could have been more readable with less comments by not using a single monolithic regular expression :-)

Comment: @delnan: You're right on both counts. The parens were a leftover from a previous version, I've now removed them. The `^` is indeed unnecessary, but since it doesn't hurt and makes the intention clearer, I've left it in.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my first post on SO.
Pleeaaase, correct my english whenever it will be needed, I do ask you.

I think that any of the following REs fits right:

```
'(?=.{4,30}\Z)(?=.*-)[-a-z0-9/]+\Z'

'(?=.{4,30}\Z)[a-z0-9/]\*-[-a-z0-9/]\*\Z'

'(?=.{4,30}\Z)(?:[a-z0-9/]+|)-[-a-z0-9/]*\Z'
```